# Create html table in php using foreach() and strpos()

Tags: javascript, php

A table is being built with every product/brand/condition/qty added and sent to my email. However, if one is left blank, it will destroy the table format. I have tried if/ else statements, isset/!empty, along with anything else I can think of. I want to add blank columns/ rows to insert if left blank.

- Since I am using a counter (product_1, product_2) with every added item and there is no limit, I am using strpos to *find* and "quickly" add to the table.

-- I am unable to attach pictures with this being my first post. --

**Here's what I have now and works great when no fields are left blank:**

```
$content .= "<table rules='all' style='border-color: #666; width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto;'>\r\n";    

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $partqty = strpos($key, 'Part_Quantity');
    $partcond = strpos($key, 'Part_Condition');
    $partbrand = strpos($key, 'Part_Brand');
    $partmodel = strpos($key, 'Part_Model');
        if ($partqty === 0) {
        $content .= "<tr>\r\n";         
        $content .= "   <td style='width:15%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }           
        if ($partcond === 0) {      
        $content .= "   <td style='width:65%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }   
        if ($partbrand === 0) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partmodel === 0) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        $content .= "</tr>\r\n";            
    }
}

$content .= "</table>\r\n";
```

**This is an idea of what I would like to do but doesn't work.**

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $partqty = strpos($key, 'Part_Quantity');
    $partcond = strpos($key, 'Part_Condition');
    $partbrand = strpos($key, 'Part_Brand');
    $partmodel = strpos($key, 'Part_Model');
        if ($partqty === 0) {
        $content .= "<tr>\r\n";         
        $content .= "   <td style='width:15%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partqty === false) {
        $content .= "<tr>\r\n";         
        $content .= "   <td style='width:15%;'><input value='empty' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }       
        if ($partcond === 0) {      
        $content .= "   <td style='width:65%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partcond === false) {      
        $content .= "   <td style='width:65%;'><input value='empty' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partbrand === 0) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partbrand === false) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='empty' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        }
        if ($partmodel === 0) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='" . $value . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        $content .= "</tr>\r\n";            
    }
        if ($partmodel === false) {
        $content .= "   <td style='width:10%;'><input value='empty' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>\r\n";
        $content .= "</tr>\r\n";            
    }
}
```

Print_r example :

```
Array (
  [Part_Quantity_1] => 1
  [Part_Condition_1] => New
  [Part_Brand_1] => brand1
  [Part_Model_1] => model1
  [Part_Quantity_2] => 2
  [Part_Condition_2] => New
  [Part_Brand_2] => 2
  [Part_Model_2] => 2
  [Estimated_Total] => 0
  [Estimated_Hours] => 0
  [Name] => JohnDoe
  [Email] => test@test.com
  [Email_Verify] => test@test.com
  [Confirmation] => I agree
  [NameID] => form2-name
  [EmailID] => form2-email
  [HoursID] => form2-hours
  [AjaxCall] => form2_ajax
)
```

Comment: You don't need to end every line with `\r\n`. The closure of a `</tr>` will make the next element be on a new line

Comment: Also 0 and false are the same, you can just run `if(!$partmodel)`. Then wrap the `$value` with something like `(is_int($value))?$value:'empty'`

Comment: Makes it much easier to read when I am looking at it when troubleshooting in html editor, hence the \r\n.

Comment: What is your post data? I can't see any reason why you would be using `strpos()` on the $key. Also what are you expecting the output to look like

Comment: Can you show us what `$_POST` looks like so we can help you better?

Comment: I only know the beginning of each elements name but with an added counter so I'm using strpos. i.e. name="product_1" value="blah", name="product_2" value="bleh"...and counts as many as they add. Four categories in each row and need to have product_1 go with brand_1, qty_1, cond_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
// set dummy $_POST
$_POST = [
    'Part_Quantity_1' => '1',
    'Part_Condition_1' => 'New',
    'Part_Brand_1' => 'brand1',
    'Part_Model_1' => 'model1',
    'Part_Quantity_2' => '2',
    'Part_Condition_2' => 'New',
    'Part_Brand_2' => '2',
    'Part_Model_2' => '2',
    'Part_Quantity_3' => '3',
    'Estimated_Total' => '0',
    'Estimated_Hours' => '0',
    'Name' => 'JohnDoe',
    'Email' => 'test@test.com',
    'Email_Verify' => 'test@test.com',
    'Confirmation' => 'I agree',
    'NameID' => 'form2-name',
    'EmailID' => 'form2-email',
    'HoursID' => 'form2-hours',
    'AjaxCall' => 'form2_ajax'
];

$parts = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('#^Part_(?<type>Quantity|Condition|Brand|Model)_(?<counter>\d+)$#', $key, $matches) === 1) {
        if (!isset($parts[$matches['counter']])) {
            $parts[$matches['counter']] = array_fill_keys(['Quantity', 'Condition', 'Brand','Model'], 'empty');
        }
        $parts[$matches['counter']][$matches['type']] = $value;
    }
}

$rows = array_map(function($part) {
    $cells = [];
    foreach ($part as $key => $value) {
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        $width = null;

        switch($key) {
        case 'Quantity':
            $width = "15%";
            break;
        case 'Condition':
            $width = "60%";
            break;
        case 'Brand':
        case 'Model':
            $width = "10%";
            break;
        }

        $cells[] = "    <td style=\"border: none; width: {$width};\"><input value=\"{$value}\"></td>";
    }

    return implode("\n", $cells);
}, $parts);

$table = "<tr>\n" . implode("\n<tr>\n", $rows) . "\n</tr>\n";

echo $table;
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but will go through every key present and create a lot of "empty" cells/rows nor does it break up nicely with qty/cond/brand/model in the same row.

Comment: you need 4 columns always? Can i see $_POST structure?

Comment: Can you paste result of `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: Thanks! and also, what version your using php?

Comment: All data is serialized via ajax and sent to php to get processed. I am using PHP 5.5.12

Comment: i changed implementation. check again!

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! I accepted your answer. I can't vote up but it deserves it. Thanks to everyone else for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the expected output or the post data is but this should work, it's untested though. I also noticed you aren't outputting the heading of the rows anywhere

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'Part_Quantity':
            $width = "15%";
        break;
        case 'Part_Condition':
            $width = "60%";
        break;
        default:
            $width = "10%";
        break;
    }
    $content = "<tr>";
    $content .= "<td style='width:".$width.";'><input value='" . (is_int($value) ? $value : 'empty' . "' style='border: none; width:100%;'></td>";
    $content .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Very cool idea, but doesn't work right. It also affects the rest of the post data and throws it into the table. It also does not add <td>, only a whole lot of <tr>'s after each key & value. Any suggestions?